# ggplot showing multiple axis unexpectedly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot, axis-labels

I'm trying to make a scatter plot of the following data:

```
cellines     TFs                V3                V4
1     A549    ATF3 -63.6777147567198  15.8519394572415
2     A549    BCL3 -61.1807150847571  15.8274988278844
3     A549 BHLHE40  49.0082575992423  43.4891023541967
4     A549   CEBPB  18.9039338584414 -66.8282282747146
5     A549    CTCF  52.6089140710441 -42.5728622947219
6     A549    ELF1  27.3004998230339  42.2866894056312
```

and the code:

```
p <- ggplot(tsne_plot,aes(x=V3,y=V4,col=TFs))
p + geom_point() + theme(legend.position="none")
```

but Here's what I get:
[image: Plot showing unexpected axis]

And I also get the error:

```
TEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
TEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

The goal is to make a plot with only one axis. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Your data is not numeric. That's all you need to fix. Check why it was imported as character/factors or coerce to numeric.

Comment: I'm only plotting V3 and V4 here and they are numeric. The TF is a label for the color and I've tried to convert to integer values but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Check str(tsne_plot) and you'll see that the data is not numeric.

Comment: can you share a reproducible example to produce your plot above? I tried with your 6 rows of records, and didn't have the issue of multiple axis. You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to produce a reproducible example

Comment: @shaojl7 There are no multiple axes in OP's plot. There are many decimal numbers as axis breaks, which results in overplotting of axis text.

Comment: @Roland You're right. I put the numeric part in one data frame and color table in another one and the problem is gone. Not a direct solution but works conveniently. Thanks!

Comment: That should not be necessary. A data.frame can hold different data types. The problem is probably in how you build it. Possibly you are using cbind to create a matrix somewhere which is not needed and results in such issues.

Comment: Note that using two data.frames can result in a wrong color mapping in ggplot2.

Comment: Exactly! I used cbind to construct the data frame! Now I changed it to df$V3 <- V3 and it's fixed! Thank you so much!